# Hidding api key in front end application

Tags: node.js, polymer, polymer-3.x

I am using polymer js for front-end and I am having a file where I am using google-map API how can I hide the API without using "dotenv" .I am using loopback framework.
How can i store the api key securely in backend and access it in the front-end.

It is recommended to have api key in backend and access it in client side , can anyone please explain a better way to achieve it.
For example-
in client side code i have js file i am using it this way..
google-map on-tap="_changeHeight" data-args="map" fit-to-markers map="{{map}}" max-zoom="18" id="googleMapLocatorAtmDetails" api-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

But the recommended way is to store the api-key in server-side and access it in client side any idea?

Comment: You cant hide anything in frontend code. dotenv file wont help you with that either as ultimately it will put the key in your code somewhere. Anyone with sufficient time and knowledge will be able to read everything thats part of the frontend code.

Comment: If you want to hide sensitive data (API keys, passwords...etc.) you have to store and use them in the server side because in the end, the front end code has to be converted to plain text. No matter how obfuscated, it can be interpreted for values (and keys cannot be changed anyway). One of the common ways to do this is environmental variables, which are variables that are "baked into" the environment (server app). `.dotenv` just simulates this in the development environment and will not help you in a deployment in the end.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not lock it down to your domain name in google maps?

Go to google cloud -> API & Services -> credential

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nitin, but one issue like I am hardcoding the api-key value in the code how can i stop exposing it.

Comment: Bit late but I thought I will answer anyway Google has already thought of this and this is why you have the option of locking the API key to specific domain. This way the API key is useless even if someone gets hold of your API key.